# should getManager be used in every method typeorm

Tags: typeorm, nest

I'm a little confused as to wheather to use getManager() inside every function or should i make it as a class property like so manager = getManager() and access it like so this.manager. Is it the same or is there something i should be aware of when using one of the methods above. Thanks ahead.